# How could I search for specific condition including empty value

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I want to search products by `year` ,

The year should newer than `2011`

`Product.find({year: {%gt: 2011}})`

- Product A year:2012
- Product B year:2013
- Product C year:2009
- Product D year:nil

But some Product without the `year` information, but I still want to get them.

The expect result is product `a,b,d`

How could I rewrite the query to reach my expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Product.find({$or: [{year: {$gt: 2011}}, {year: {$exists: false}}]})
```

This will get you the documents that have `year` field greater than `2011` **and** the documents that have `null` as the value of field `year` (which is the same as if the `year` filed is not defined).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
Product.find({$or: [{year: {$gt: 2011}}, {year: null}]})
```

This query will find `year` greater than `2011` or `year` is null.